# Sublime text 3 Anaconda autocomplete not working

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have an issue when I try to edit Python code in Sublime on Mac OS. The autocomplete is not working in Sublime but is working well in the terminal.

I checked several things between Sublime and terminal.

The Python version was the same as Anaconda 3.7.3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
‘3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) \n[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]’
```

In the Anaconda.sublime-settings:

```
“python_interpreter”: “/Users/J/anaconda3/bin/python”,
“disable_anaconda_completion”: false,
```

When I tried coding in Sublime nothing shows:

[image]

But it works well in the terminal.

[image]

Code can execute well on both sides.

Comment: Sorry did you make it work? I have similar symptoms,  (not picking up the interpreter) with the setup working on macos and not working on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [the documentation](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) about installing Sublime Text 3 and Anaconda and it is working well for me.

1. Install Sublime Text 3 at http://www.sublimetext.com/3
2. Install package control at https://packagecontrol.io/installation
3. Manually install Anaconda at https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/archive/v2.1.14.tar.gz

The packages directory can be found in:

```
Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Subime Text 3/Packages
Windows: %APPDATA%\\Sublime Text 3
```

Restart Sublime Text 3 and enjoy.

Comment: I manually installed them step by step but it's still not working. Actually, I didn't find the packages directory. It hasn't been created. But the interpreter did work well in the terminal. It seems nothing wrong with the anaconda. But Sublime cannot load the interpreter.